# MySQL ADD to column

Tags: mysql

How would I go about "adding" data to existing data in a column?

For an example:
I have values

> Mary has 2 brothers

in column **"family"**, now I want to ADD

> and one sister

to **"family"** in order to have

> Mary has 2 brothers and one sister

Comment: You mean `concat`? like this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, I guess you need `concat` function in update statement like this :

```
update your_table
set family = concat(family,' and one sister')
where id = 'blabla'
```

And this is for `select` statement :

```
select concat(family,' and one sister') as family
from your table
```